# How do I create a VSTS project to use the Scrum process?

Tags: azure-devops

I just created a new Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) project. It created it using Git, which is good. But it also created it using the Agile process for project management. At no point, that I could see, did it give me a chance to chose. How do I create a new team project in VSTS to use both Git and Scrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new VSTS design you need to press on "Create Project", **click on "Advanced"**, in "Version Control" choose `Git`, in "Work item process" choose `Scrum`:

[image]

In the old design, there is no "Advanced" and you can choose the template easily:

[image]